# Does it matter in functional analysis whether we know (something about) a basis?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis

Let's look at a few spaces in functional analysis: $(L^p,C^n([0,1]), l^p,c,c_0,d)$
I actually only know the basis of one of these spaces. Which is the one that belongs to d, given by the unit sequences $e_i=(0,...,0,1,0,....)$. So this one has a countable basis. Unfortunatelyy it is not a banach space, so it is a pretty useless example. But what is about the other spaces. Do they have a countable basis. Is it even possible to write down a simple basis for them? Is it even of any use to know a basis in functional analysis?

Comment: If by basis you mean basis in the algebraic sense, or Hamel basis, then a Banach space cannot have a countable basis. The pertinent concept of basis is then rather Schauder basis.

Comment: Is it easy to see that a Banach space cannot have a countable Hamel basis?

Comment: It follows from the Baire Category Theorem.  If it did, the space would be a union of a collection of finite dimensional subspaces (the spans of the first n basis vectors), which are nowhere dense.

Comment: cool, thank you. did not know this.

Comment: Depends on what you can work with. If you have Baire's theorem, then yes. A finite-dimensional subspace is closed, hence nowhere dense, if the space is infinite-dimensional, and if it had a countable basis, it would be a countable union of finite-dimensional subspaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schauder bases are useful in functional analysis; algebraic/Hamel bases are not. Open the first volume of *Classical Banach spaces* by Lindenstrauss of Tzafriri, and you'll quickly find more about Schauder bases than you ever wanted.

Some examples: [Walsh basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walsh_function) for $L^p$ is a neat construction which is useful in signal processing. It even [works for $p=1$](http://calculus7.org/2012/01/28/the-walsh-basis/), which is a pretty nasty space. For $C^{(n)}[0,1]$, the seemingly natural choice (complex exponentials / trig function) fails, but one can use antiderivatives of order $(n+1)$ of the [Haar functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet#Haar_system_on_the_unit_interval_and_related_systems). For $c_0$, the sequences in your post form a Schauder basis. For $c$, throw in a constant sequence.